# Existence of a smooth extension

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, smooth-manifolds, sobolev-spaces, cones

In the three dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$ let us define the hypersurface
$$ S= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3\,:\, z^2= x^2+y^2\}.$$

Suppose that $f \in C^{\infty}(S)$. Does there exist $u\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^3)$ such that $u|_{S} = f$?

Comment: What is $C^\infty(S)$? $S$ is not a manifold near zero, so it is not clear what do you mean by this.

Comment: Let us say that f is smooth away from the zero on S and at zero all order of tangential derivatives vanish.

Comment: Can't you do something like this: let's slice the space into the regions $2^{-k} < x^2+y^2+z^2 < 2^{-k+1}$, on each such region we can achieve extrapolation, and then have bounds go to zero when we approach zero (and also add diagonal argument somewhere to make all the derivatives converge)? Sounds pretty unpleasant, but plausible

Comment: Whitney extension theorem?